# Conditional Envers Auditing

Tags: hibernate, jboss7.x, hibernate-envers

I have a requirement where I want to audit records only on change of Status field. I've followed documentation chapter tutorial "15.8. Conditional auditing".

Step 1: Turn off automatic Envers event listeners registration. I have following:

```
<prop key="hibernate.listeners.envers.autoRegister">false</prop>
```

Step 2: Create subclasses for appropriate event listeners.

```
public class DeleteEnversListener extends EnversPostDeleteEventListenerImpl {   
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5906427978349712224L;
    private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(DeleteEnversListener.class);

    public DeleteEnversListener(AuditConfiguration enversConfiguration) {
        super(enversConfiguration);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostDelete(PostDeleteEvent event) {
        log.info("!!! just logging entity !! "+ event.getEntity());
        super.onPostDelete(event);
    }   
}
```

In similar way, I have

- InsertEnversListener
- UpdateEnversListener
- DeleteEnversListener
- CollectionRecreateEnversListener
- PreCollectionRemoveEnversListener
- PreCollectionUpdateEnversListener

Step 3: Create your own implementation of `org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator`

```
public class CustomEnversIntegrator extends EnversIntegrator   {

    private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(CustomEnversIntegrator.class);

    @Override
    public void integrate(Configuration configuration,
            SessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory,
            SessionFactoryServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) {

        super.integrate(configuration, sessionFactory, serviceRegistry);
        final AuditConfiguration enversConfiguration = AuditConfiguration.getFor( configuration, serviceRegistry.getService( ClassLoaderService.class ) );
        EventListenerRegistry listenerRegistry = serviceRegistry.getService( EventListenerRegistry.class );

        System.out.println("Registering event listeners");
        if (enversConfiguration.getEntCfg().hasAuditedEntities()) {
            listenerRegistry.appendListeners(EventType.POST_INSERT, new InsertEnversListener(enversConfiguration));
            listenerRegistry.appendListeners(EventType.POST_UPDATE, new UpdateEnversListener(enversConfiguration));
            listenerRegistry.appendListeners(EventType.POST_DELETE, new DeleteEnversListener(enversConfiguration ) );
            listenerRegistry.appendListeners(EventType.POST_COLLECTION_RECREATE, new CollectionRecreateEnversListener(enversConfiguration ) );
            listenerRegistry.appendListeners(EventType.PRE_COLLECTION_REMOVE, new PreCollectionRemoveEnversListener(enversConfiguration ) );
            listenerRegistry.appendListeners(EventType.PRE_COLLECTION_UPDATE, new PreCollectionUpdateEnversListener(enversConfiguration ) );
        }

    }
}
```

Step 4: For the integrator to be automatically used when Hibernate starts up, you will need to add a `META-INF/services/org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator` file. Here is content of `org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator` file

```
com.hib.sample.listener.CustomEnversIntegrator
```

I am not sure, if I am missing anything.  I am using JBOSS AS 7.0 with Hibernate 4.1.8

Comment: And what happens currently?
Is your custom integrator code called at all?

Comment: @adamw: I have added sysout statements to integrator code, but none of them are appearing. It seems Services are not recognized by JBOSS. I have created project using Eclipse 4.2 Juno as Dynamic Web project.  **Not sure whether Location of META-INF is correct**. Any advice..

Comment: Did you check the resulting jar/war, if it has the file in the correct place?

Comment: @Adamw, Sorry for delayed reply, Yes META-INF is located in WAR file at G:\jboss-as-web-7.0.2.Final\standalone\deployments\sample.war\META-INF\services\

Comment: And the classes are directly in the war as well, not in a .jar?

Comment: Hi Shirish, were you able to solve the problem?

Answer (score 13):

Here is a Spring-only solution for the conditional `Envers` auditing without an ugly `META-INF` folder etc. All what you need is a bean in your configuration class and a `CustomEnversEventListener`.

```
@Bean
public EventListenerRegistry listenerRegistry(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    ServiceRegistryImplementor serviceRegistry = entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactoryImpl.class).getServiceRegistry();

    final EnversService enversService = serviceRegistry.getService(EnversService.class);
    EventListenerRegistry listenerRegistry = serviceRegistry.getService(EventListenerRegistry.class);

    listenerRegistry.setListeners(EventType.POST_UPDATE, new CustomEnversEventListener(enversService));
    return listenerRegistry;
  }
```

and

```
  public class CustomEnversEventListener extends EnversPostUpdateEventListenerImpl {

    CustomEnversEventListener(EnversService enversService) {
      super(enversService);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostUpdate(PostUpdateEvent event) {

      // custom conditional stuff

      super.onPostUpdate(event);
    }
  }
```

If you want to customise only one listener i.e. EnversPostUpdateEventListener,  you don't need to disable `hibernate.listeners.envers.autoRegister` in order to let Envers register the other listener.

Then you can override `Envers` listeners by `listenerRegistry.setListeners` or append by `listenerRegistry.appendListeners`

Answer (score 1):

Try to place integrator file into:

```
sample.war\WEB-INF\classes\META-INF\services\...
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe...

In my case, I use Maven, and I had to include in the `pom.xml`, the following line :    `<include>**/*.Integrator</include>`, because the file was not packaged in the `.ear`.

My `pom.xml`:

```
<resources>
       <resource>
           <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
           <filtering>true</filtering>
           <includes>
                <include>**/*.xml</include>
               <include>**/*.Integrator</include>
           </includes>
       </resource>
       ...
```

Answer (score 0):

creating a file **org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator** (containing the qualified name of my custom integrator) in a folder **META-INF/services/** under **src/main/resources** of my maven project made my custom integrator code be called.

Answer (score 0):

@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example.demo"}, lazyInit = true)

Adding lazyInit = true, triggered the custom integrator for me.