# Audit trail with Hibernate Envers: How to trail only selected changes on entity?

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I have already implemented audit trail using hibernate envers for my entities and it works fine. Any changes (insert,update,delete) are stored in _AUD tables.

Now I want to extend my audit and trail changes when one entity property has changed only. I want to store that change to additional table. In addition to the existing TABLE_AUD table which is tracking all changes in the entity, I need a second table TABLE_AUD2 that will track changes based on the one entity property only. What is important: the thing relates to the same entity.

Is it possible in envers? What can you suggest to implement such a requirement?

Comment: Were you able to get this done? There is a similar question that might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14250612/conditional-envers-auditing

Comment: I holded this task for a while. Later I will try to implement AuditEventListener. As I see it is not exactly what I need because I need two mechanisms working separately but simultaneously